# How can I create a registry key on a remote computer under the SID

Tags: powershell, scripting, registry

I can get as far as creating the PSDrive. The issue I am having is that the SID is different on every machine.

```
New-PSSession Device_Name_Here
Enter-Pssession Device_Name_Here
get-psdrive
New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS 
New-Item -Path HKU:\" + $SID + "\Printers\Connections
Exit-PSSession
Get-PSSession | Remove-Pssession
```

Comment: I need to target all users. I have a separate script that installs printers for all users of a computer. It works fine except it relies on the key already existing on the device. this key gets created wien the first network printer is installed. I need to create the \Printers\Connections regardless of the SID.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```bash
# Note: You may pass *multiple* device (computer) names to -ComputerName
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Device_Name_Here {
  Get-ChildItem 'registry::HKEY_USERS' |
    ForEach-Object {
       $destPath = "registry::$($_.Name)\Printers\Connections"
       if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $destPath)) {
         New-Item $destPath
       }
    }
}
```

- There is no strict need to map a drive in order to access the `HKEY_USERS` registry hive - using the `registry::` *[provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix* is enough.
- The above targets *all* subkeys of the `HKEY_USERS` hive, even though some may not represent actual *users*.
- [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) is used for *unattended* remote execution.

  - By contrast, [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession) is only intended for *interactive* use.